# Como criar relacionamento de tabelas no mysql

Tags: php, java, mysql

estou a começar com base de dados relacional e tenho dificuldade de relacionar as tabelas, sou leigo na matéria. Peço ajuda por meio de indicação de um/alguns livros claros e objectivos sobre o assunto.
Grato pela atenção

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mposso

INNER JOIN ou LEFT JOIN, exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM professores p
INNER JOIN alunos a ON a.idProfessor = p.id
```